# Destroy all session scoped bean of a class

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, javabeans, session-scope

Is there any way to destroy all created session scoped bean of a particular class (and let spring recreate when needed) ?

For example, 2 users visit the application, and then there will be 1 bean for each of the user. I would like to destroy all these 2 beans.

Use case:

a admin is updating the menu bar. menu bar list data are stored in a session scoped bean. the admin's bean should be destroyed and the menu bar should be updated. and of course the others' menu should be updated as well, so the others bean should be destroyed as well.

note 1: different user may see different menu, so the bean is session scoped, not singleton.

note 2: i do not want to invalidate whole session of the user, but just only that bean

i found [this way](http://forum.spring.io/forum/spring-projects/container/36024-clearing-session-scope-bean) to destroy the current scope bean. but i am not able to destroy bean from other session.

```
((ScopedObject) myBean).removeFromScope();
```

Thanks a lot !!

Comment: The proper fix would be to avoid storing this non-session-related data in the session. Or at the very least to check if there was an update when accessing it, and refresh it if needed.

Comment: I wanted to do some caching for the menu, and different user may have different menu (so i guess this is session-related? please tell me if my understanding is wrong). so what i can think to increase the efficiency is to only refreshing the menu data when needed (updated)

Comment: It's not really session-related because the data it contains isn't valid for the duration of the session (as your problem shows), and its data isn't controlled by the user which the session belongs to. Again, I would make everything stateless. If there is really a performance problem, then cache the whole configuration in a singleton bean, and compute the user-specific menu whenever needed. If there is still a performance problem, store the menu in the session, but check if it must be recomputed every time it's displayed.

Comment: i see. so probably i should follow your approach instead of messing with the user session! thanks for your suggestion !

Comment: You cannot touch a session from another users session. If that would be possible that would be quitte some security hole. As @JBNizet pointed out the data isn’t really session related, so just put it in a cache and clear that after the updating.

Answer (score 0):

Destroying beans and recreating them seems overkill and a little messy too.
For such approaches I would favor events and Spring provides a Spring Event API (`spring-context` dependency).
You could inject an `ApplicationEventPublisher` instance in the bean class that provokes the state change for some other beans and these beans could register a even listener (  `@EventListener(condition = "..."))` to read this change event.

For example the publisher :

```
@Component
public class PublisherBean{

    private final ApplicationEventPublisher publisher;

    @Autowired
    public PublisherBean(ApplicationEventPublisher publisher) { ... }

    public void createOrder(Order order) {
        // ....
        this.publisher.publishEvent(new OrderCreatedEvent(order)); 
    }    
}
```

Subscribers/Listeners :

```
@Component
public class ListenerBean{

  @EventListener(condition = "#creationEvent.awesome")
  public void handleOrderCreatedEvent(CreationEvent<Order> creationEvent) {
    ... 
  }

}
```

You could see more information  [here](https://spring.io/blog/2015/02/11/better-application-events-in-spring-framework-4-2).

Comment: Are you sure that this would work with session-scoped beans? Those only really exist while a request is being processed for the session.

Comment: Honestly never tested with session scoped beans as generally I banish them and banish data in session. If the OP doesn't test this way, I could give it a go on a sample project.

Comment: tried and seems that it does not pass through session scoped bean (?) i am not sure if i write correctly though

```applicationEventPublisher.publishEvent(new CmsMenuUpdatedEvent(this));```

`@EventListener() public void handleMenuUpdate(CmsMenuUpdatedEvent event) {}`

but thanks for telling me about this amazing event listener function !!

Comment: and one more question, when would you choose for publishing a event and handling in the listener, or when would you choose for directly call the method from the listener ?

update: actually i can make another research :) thanks anyway